# Extract int from stream in Java

Tags: java

I was looking through some Java code and came accross this...

```
public static int readVInt(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    byte b = (byte)in.read();

    if(b == (byte) 0x80)
        throw new RuntimeException("Attempting to read null value as int");

    int value = b & 0x7F;
    while ((b & 0x80) != 0) {
        b = (byte)in.read();
        value <<= 7;
        value |= (b & 0x7F);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Won't value always be b and won't the while always return 0? Any explination because I don't understand it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that value will always be `b` and that the while always returns 0? It's hard to explain where your understanding goes wrong unless you tell us how you come to your conclusion.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, which I'm sure I don't, is the following...

Comment: The code is trying to read a 32-bit int value that could be encoded in 1 to 5 bytes (technically it could be any number of bytes but since an `int` only holds 32 bits, it will overflow anything more than 5 bytes long). Each byte only contains 7 bits that contribute to the final value. The code looks alright and should return a real 32-bit value. And the return value is not always equal to `b`.

Comment: Thanks, you made me think again and I figured some things out... I wasn't thinking outside the box (ñ, emolji etc).